# How can I implement Firebase in my iOS app to upload/download SceneKit files?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, scenekit, arkit

I have an iOS app that I use for image recognition augmented reality, specifically it's used for art exhibitions. I want to be able to include all of the previous assets/scenes from previous exhibitions into the app, but the problem with that is - the app would be **tremendously large**.

I'm pretty low level into coding - I've tried implementing On Demand Resources with no luck and decided to move towards Firebase. I've seen a good amount of references for using Firebase for tableviews, images, and text; but very little that has to do with **3D SceneKit files**. As I said, I am pretty low level so it is difficult for me to translate the former references into a format that works for SceneKit.

If anyone can help me with properly **implementing Firebase into my app**, it would be greatly appreciated! I have a lot planned in which it will be necessary for.

Also, so far I have set up Firebase with my app on the website, downloaded and installed podfiles and am currently working in the workspace that was created by it.

Have been going off of this video to get started: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIQsQ2injLo&t=1111s

```
class ViewControllerTwo: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet var sceneView3: ARSCNView!


var PNoneNode: SCNNode?
var PNtwoNode: SCNNode?
var PNthreeNode: SCNNode?
var PNfourNode: SCNNode?
var PNfiveNode: SCNNode?
var PNsixNode: SCNNode?
var PNsevenNode: SCNNode?
var PNeightNode: SCNNode?
var MrHappyNode: SCNNode?
var ShowOverNode: SCNNode?
var PneumaLogoNode: SCNNode?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//This is where I began  attempting to implement Firebase but I am aware it is not functional, just looking for help

    func scenes(){

        let scenes = SCNScene(named: "Pneuma.scnassets/PNone.scn")

  let ref: DatabaseReference!

      ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("Scenes").childByAutoId().setValue(scenes)


    }
    sceneView3.delegate = self
    sceneView3.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

    // This is where the AR code begins

    let PNoneScene = SCNScene(named: "Pneuma.scnassets/PNone.scn")
    let PNtwoScene = SCNScene(named: "Pneuma.scnassets/PNtwo.scn")
```

Comment: Super interesting project and fortunately, there's a super simple answer. You may be using DAE or SCN files. Those can both be easily stored in [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) and retrieved and used like any file. Here's the guide on [Uploading Files to Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files). You will keep a reference to those files in Firebase Real Time Database or Firestore. I would suggest going through the Realtime Database [Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start) and read/write some strings.

Comment: Appreciate it! Thank you for your kindness